# Query Account history using API

Tags: api, account, php

Is there a way to query the account history using php and the API? I have some accounts that got updated unnecessarily and I need to view the history to programmatically update them all back to their correct stage. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Yes, every object with history tracking enabled has queryable shadow object. In this case it's simply `AccountHistory`.

Just experiment with query similar to this

```
SELECT AccountId, Account.Name, CreatedBy.Name,CreatedDate,Field, OldValue,NewValue 
FROM AccountHistory
ORDER BY AccountId, CreatedDate DESC
```